# How does linux redirect IO work internally

Tags: linux, shell

When we use the redirect IO operator for a shell script does the operator keep all the data to be written in memory and write it all at once or does write it to file line by line.

Here is what i am working on.

I have about 200 small files ~1000 lines each in a specific format. I want to process (do a regex and change the format a little) each line in all the files and have the new transformed lines in a single combined file.

I have a transformscript.sh that takes a single file and applies the transformation. I run it in the following manner

```
sh transformscript.sh somefile.txt > newfile.txt
```

This works fine and fast for a single file.

How do i extend to do it for all the files. will it be efficient to change transformscript.sh to take a directory as argument instead of filename and add a for loop to transform all the lines of all the files together. Or should I run the above trnsformscript.sh for each file and create a new file for each one and combine then separately.

Thanks.

Comment: No programming needed: `cat dir/file*glob | sh transformscript.sh /proc/self/fd/0 > newfile.txt`  Even easier if `transformscript.sh` follows the convention that `-` means read from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect operator simply opens the file for writing and passes that file descriptor to the shell as its standard output. The shell then writes to the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do NOT want to run the script separately for each file since you will incur the overhead of bash process creation for each pass.  For example:

```
# don't do it this way
for somefile in $(ls somefiles*.txt); do
  newfile=${somefile//some/new}
  sh transformscript.sh $somefile > $newfile
done
```

The above starts one shell for every file found which is pretty inefficient.  It would be better to rewrite transformscript.sh to handle multiple files if possible.  Depending on how complicated your transform is and whether you need to keep the original filenames, you might be able to use a single sed process.  For example, assume you have 200 files named test1.txt through test200.txt all with a "Hello world" line you want to change to "Hello joe".  You could do something as simple a this:

```
sed -i.save 's/Hello world/Hello joe/' test*.txt
```

The -i tells sed to do an "in place" edit (edit the original file) and the optional ".save" argument to -i makes a backup copy of the original file with a .save extension before editing the original file.  Note, this will leave the original contents in the .save files and the new content in the files with the original name which may not be what you want.